# How to access a list in OCaml

Tags: find, ocaml

I want to write a function that could check every item in a list is `true` or `false`. If at least one element is `false`, it will return `true`, so that:

```
assert_eq "checkFalse [true; false; true]" (checkFalse [true; true; true]) false;
assert_eq "checkFalse [false; false]" (checkFalse [false; true]) true;
```

I am an absolute beginner in OCaml and I don't know how to approach this. I tried using a for loop, something like:

```
let rec checkFalse (bools: bool list) : bool =
for i = 0 to bools.length do
    if bools.length == false then false
    else... (I don't know how to continue)
```

Then it said "Unbound record field...."

I also tried using find like: 
`if (find false bools != Not_found) then true else false`

But my ways did not work. I came from a Java background.

Comment: You rarely need to specify types in OCaml.  `let rec checkFalse bools =` is identical to what you have written.

Comment: @Niki: However, it can be helpful for beginners, as it might make error messages easier.

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should never use `==` and `!=`, but only `=` and `<>`, which do test equality in the way you would expect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the `List` module: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html specifically the `exists` method.  For what you want, you can simply do this:

```
List.exists (fun x -> not x) [true;true;...;false;...]
```

The `exists` function will return true if any element in the list satisfies the predicate (the function).  In this case, the predicate is `fun x -> not x` which will return true if `x` is false.

For general list access, you generally do this using pattern matching and recursion, or using the functions `iter`, `map`, `fold_left`, and `fold_right` (among others).  Here's an implementation of `exists` using pattern matching:

```
let rec exists f l = match l with
  | [] -> false (* the list is empty, return false *)
  | h::t -> if (f h) then true (* the list has a head and a (possibly empty) tail.  Check the return value of the predicate 'f' when applied to the head *)
    else exists f t (* the predicate is false, recursively call the `exists` function on the tail *)
```

edit: as Chuck has posted, instead of `fun x -> not x` you can just simply use `not`.

Another possibility is to use the `mem` function:

```
List.mem false bools
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let rec checkFalse xs =
    match xs with [] -> false
    | false :: _ -> true
    | _ :: tl -> checkFalse tl;;
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would just be `let checkFalse = List.exists not`.

`List.exists` takes a function and a list as arguments, and tells if the function you passed returns true for any element in the list. `not` returns the negation of a bool.

Answer (score 0):

let checkFalse = List.exists (fun elem -> elem = false) your_list in

doc: 
val exists : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool

exists p [a1; ...; an] checks if at least one element of the list satisfies the predicate p.

That is, it returns (p a1) || (p a2) || ... || (p an).